# Query done by SQL showing same results multiple times (multiple copies of same record in query)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba

I've got a query being made via an SQL statement. I'm getting the correct results, just each result is repeated 4 times in the query. I'm confused as to why I am getting 4 copies of the same result.

Here is my code for the form:

```
Dim strTables As String
Private Sub btnFollowUpQs_Click()
    If (btnFollowUpQs.Value = True) Then
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(btnFollowUpQs.Caption)
        Dim fld As DAO.Field
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Me.lstVariablesFollowUpQs.AddItem (fld.Name)
        Next
        Set fld = Nothing
        db.Close
        strTables = strTables + "," + btnFollowUpQs.Caption
    Else
        lstVariablesFollowUpQs.RowSource = ""
        strTables = Replace(strTables, "," + btnFollowUpQs.Caption, "")
    End If
    Debug.Print strTables
End Sub

Private Sub btnBaseline_Click()
    If (btnBaseline.Value = True) Then
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(btnBaseline.Caption)
        Dim fld As DAO.Field
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Me.lstVariablesBaseline.AddItem (fld.Name)
        Next
        Set fld = Nothing
        db.Close
        strTables = strTables + "," + btnBaseline.Caption
    Else
        lstVariablesBaseline.RowSource = ""
        strTables = Replace(strTables, "," + btnBaseline.Caption, "")
    End If
        Debug.Print strTables
End Sub

Private Sub btnTreatments_Click()
    If (btnTreatments.Value = True) Then
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(btnTreatments.Caption)
        Dim fld As DAO.Field
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Me.lstVariablesTreatments.AddItem (fld.Name)
        Next
        Set fld = Nothing
        db.Close
        strTables = strTables + "," + btnTreatments.Caption
    Else
        lstVariablesTreatments.RowSource = ""
        strTables = Replace(strTables, "," + btnTreatments.Caption, "")
    End If
        Debug.Print strTables
End Sub

Private Sub btnQuestionnaires_Click()
    If (btnQuestionnaires.Value = True) Then
        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(btnQuestionnaires.Caption)
        Dim fld As DAO.Field
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            Me.lstVariablesQuestionnaires.AddItem (fld.Name)
        Next
        Set fld = Nothing
        db.Close
        strTables = strTables + "," + btnQuestionnaires.Caption
    Else
        lstVariablesQuestionnaires.RowSource = ""
        strTables = Replace(strTables, "," + btnQuestionnaires.Caption, "")
    End If
        Debug.Print strTables
End Sub

Private Function createSQL(ByRef lstCtrl As Control, v() As String) As String
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        With lstCtrl
            For Each varSelected In .ItemsSelected
                If Not IsNull(varSelected) Then
                    Dim sel As String
                    sel = (lstCtrl.Column(0, varSelected))
                    strSQL = strSQL + sel & " " & v(count) & " AND "
                End If
                count = count + 1
            Next
        End With

        createSQL = strSQL
End Function

Private Sub btnBuildQuery_Click()

    If Left(strTables, 1) = "," Then
        strTables = Right(strTables, Len(strTables) - 1)
    End If

    Dim tables() As String
    tables = Split(strTables, ",")


    Dim strSQL As Variant
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTables & " WHERE "

    For Each Table In tables

        Dim values() As String

        Select Case Table

        Case "tblPatientHistoryBaseline"
            values = Split(txtSearchValueBaseline, ",")
            strSQL = strSQL + createSQL(lstVariablesBaseline, values)
        Case "tblQuestionnaires"
            values = Split(txtSearchValueQuestionnaires, ",")
            strSQL = strSQL + createSQL(lstVariablesQuestionnaires, values)
        Case "tblTreatments"
            values = Split(txtSearchValueTreatments, ",")
           strSQL = strSQL + createSQL(lstVariablesTreatments, values)
        Case "tblFollowUpQs"
            values = Split(txtSearchValueFollowUpQs, ",")
           strSQL = strSQL + createSQL(lstVariablesFollowUpQs, values)
        End Select

    Next
        strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)

    Debug.Print (strSQL)
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qry" & txtQueryName, strSQL)
    DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
End Sub
```

Here's what the query returns:

```
LastName    FirstName    ID          Visit
Line        Georgia      1234567     0
Line        Georgia      1234567     0
Line        Georgia      1234567     0
Line        Georgia      1234567     0
Doe         Jane         0123456     0
Doe         Jane         0123456     0
Doe         Jane         0123456     0
Doe         Jane         0123456     0
```

Here's a sample SQL that I've generated:

```
SELECT * FROM tblQuestionnaires, tblPatientHistoryBaseline WHERE Visit = 0 AND LastName Like '*e*'
```

I'm guessing its something wrong with my SQL but I cannot figure out what.

Thanks!

'EDIT-----------------
LastName is from tblPatientHistoryBaseline, 
Visit is from tblQuestionnaires

Comment: How is `tblQuestionnaires` related to `tblPatientHistoryBaseline`? A proper JOIN would probably fix this.

Comment: They only have the same ID number (related). How would you join them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying how `tblQuestionnaires` is related to `tblPatientHistoryBaseline`? A proper `JOIN` would probably fix this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblQuestionnaires AS q
  INNER JOIN tblPatientHistoryBaseline AS ph ON q.ID = ph.ID
WHERE Visit = 0 
  AND LastName Like '*e*'
```

I am not quite sure which table the fields are coming from in your select.  The above query may still produce duplicates if there are multiple records in either table.  If that is the case you could add the DISTINCT statement to the query and specify the field you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName, ph.ID, Visit
FROM tblQuestionnaires AS q
  INNER JOIN tblPatientHistoryBaseline AS ph ON q.ID = ph.ID
WHERE Visit = 0 
  AND LastName Like '*e*'
```

***EDIT:***

```
SELECT DISTINCT ph.ID, q.fieldname, ph.fieldname, t.fieldname, f.fieldname 
FROM tblQuestionnaires AS q
  INNER JOIN tblPatientHistoryBaseline AS ph ON q.ID = ph.ID
  INNER JOIN tblTreatments AS t ON t.ID = ph.ID
  INNER JOIN tblFollowUp AS f ON f.ID = ph.ID
WHERE Visit = 0 
  AND LastName Like '*e*'
```

Comment: There can be up to 4 tables in the query - all with matching ID numbers.

Comment: What would the syntax look like for all 4 tables being in the query?? (tblTreatments and tblFollowUp)
If you don't mind!

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What does the `ID` field represent?  Is the `ID` field specific to a patient?

Comment: See my edit.  You would have to specify the exact fields you need in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Joining them is mandatory in this case. For example, your code should be written to specify only the matching rows from the questionnaire table. That is,

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblQuestionnaires, tblPatientHistoryBaseline 
WHERE Visit = 0 
AND LastName Like '*e*'
AND tblQuestionnaires.id = tblPatientHistoryBaseline.id
```

But I would also recommend using the newer (past decade anyway) syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblQuestionnaires q
  INNER JOIN tblPatientHistoryBaseline b
    ON q.id = b.id
WHERE q.Visit = 0 
AND b.LastName Like '*e*'
```

I am not sure where your VISIT column or you LASTNAME column come from, but if you prefix them with the proper alias all will be fine.